# Maximum call stack exceeded RangeError

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, stack

```
smallestInteger = (stack,numbers,k) => {
    if (stack.length == 0){
        stack.push(numbers[k]);
    }
    if (numbers[k] <= stack[stack.length-1]){
        stack.pop();
        stack.push(numbers[k]);
    } 
    console.log(`stack is ${stack}`)
    console.log("k:" + k);
    return (k == 0) ? stack[stack.length-1] : smallestInteger(stack,numbers,k-1);
}

var smallestInteger = function(numbers) {
    let stack = []; 
    let smallest = smallestInteger(stack ,numbers,numbers.length - 1);
    return `the smallest integer is ${smallest}`;
}

var testCases = [[10,2,5,7,15,9], [1,2,3,4]];
for (let testCase of testCases){
    console.log(smallestInteger(testCase));
}
```

Running `> node smallestInteger.js` gives this error:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at smallestInteger (smallestInteger.js:17:31)
    at smallestInteger (smallestInteger.js:19:17)
    at smallestInteger (smallestInteger.js:19:17)
    at smallestInteger (smallestInteger.js:19:17)
    at smallestInteger (smallestInteger.js:19:17)
    at smallestInteger (smallestInteger.js:19:17)
    at smallestInteger (smallestInteger.js:19:17)
    at smallestInteger (smallestInteger.js:19:17)
    at smallestInteger (smallestInteger.js:19:17)
    at smallestInteger (smallestInteger.js:19:17)
```

fyi the code is not reaching the console.log print statements so how do I resolve this?

The two `smallestInteger` functions have different constructors (first has 1 argument, other has 3) like an override, so I dont assume the they are replacing each other. Where are you seeing it get 2 arguments, it gets 3 arguments as expected. Finally, `smallestInteger` function is calling the `smallestInteger` helper function which does have an exit condition after the `?` that is `k == 0` so it should not go on forever. Still getting the same error

Comment: You can't have two functions of the same name (even with different signatures) exist at the same time in javascript. Give them a distinct name.

Comment: you have `smallestInteger = (stack,numbers,k) => {` ... then `var smallestInteger = function(numbers) {` ... so only the SECOND function is present, and since that simply recurses without bounds .... error ... you can't call two functions in one scope the same name, how would javascript know which function to call?

Comment: They sure are replacing each other. Javascript doesn't differentiate functions by tha signatute !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript does not allow to overload functions. For this you need to be creative. For example:

```
function smallestInteger(stack,numbers,k){
if (arguments.length == 1) {
    numbers = stack;
    stack = []; 
    let smallest = smallestInteger(stack ,numbers,numbers.length - 1);
    return `the smallest integer is ${smallest}`;
  }

if (stack.length == 0){
    stack.push(numbers[k]);
}
if (numbers[k] <= stack[stack.length-1]){
    stack.pop();
    stack.push(numbers[k]);
} 
return (k == 0) ? stack[stack.length-1] : smallestInteger(stack,numbers,k-1);
}

var testCases = [[10,2,5,7,15,9], [1,2,3,4]];
for (let testCase of testCases){
    console.log('testCase : ', testCase);
    console.log(smallestInteger(testCase));
}
```